# AWS Glue crawler is not creating table for fixed length text file with in-built classifier

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

My data file looks like this:

```
123 20180522 103122103957
123 20181004 101822106246
123 20160316 102635100963
123 20190605 101271101407
123 20160816 103294105281
123 20160820 105096101732
123 20161001 104980103955
```

When I don't use any custom classifier, it is not creating any table.

When I used custom classifier, it created the table with 21 rows detected. But the expectation is to create 7 rows with 3 columns. Can you tell me, how to fix it?

```
(?<col0>.{3})(?<col1>.{8})(?<col2>.{12})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below grok Expression

```
(?<col0>.{3})(?<col1>.{9})(?<col2>.{13})
```

To validate your expression for related data, use grok validation
https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/